# Protocol that defines observable vars

Tags: swift, key-value-observing, dynamic-dispatch

Is it possible somehow to define in a `protocol`, that some `var` should be `@objc dynamic`, so that it can be observed with `KVO`?

Comment: How do you want to use this, can you give an example?

Comment: I would like to achieve that I have a protocol which after I declare to implement, I can be sure that change in property can be observed somehow by other object. Either by KVO or delegate. For delegate I would need to implement didSet in protocol extension, but this is also not possible

Comment: Is the class which implements the protocol supposed to work together with another class, like the objects in the content of `NSTreeController`? `NSTreeController` has keypath properties. The objects in its content must be KVO compliant for these keypaths. Let the class which implements of the protocol somehow provide an observable keypath.